Angular/Bootstrap validation issues
I have the following code for state selection in an Angular 18 site I'm working on.
<select class="form-select" id="state" name="state" required [(ngModel)]="info.state">
    <option [ngValue]="null" disabled>Select...</option>
    <option *ngFor="let x of stateList" [value]="x.value">{{x.text}}</option>
</select>
<div class="invalid-feedback">
    <fa-icon [icon]="fasExclamationCircle"></fa-icon> This field is required.
</div>

I initialize info.state to null when it's created, so the disabled option shows in the select control.  If I immediately apply .was-validated to the form, the select gets a green border, green check and the "required" message isn't shown.  The control itself is :valid, but has the .ng-invalid class.  This doesn't seem to be working how I'd like.
I can get it all working by taking out the disabled option and not having anything shown or selected by default.  I can also add a directive that will add .is-invalid as a class when the disabled item is selected, but that only allows the "required" message to show - it's still green with a checkmark.
My UI/UX team wants the "Select" to be shown and doesn't want to alter the default bootstrap CSS for fear of making it harder to maintain in future updates.  If I could do that, I'd replace :valid with .ng-invalid in the styles and be done.  But that's not an option right now.
Any other ideas on how I get the control to fall to :invalid in this scenario?  A directive I can add or some other way to change things and still get what I want?  Thoughts?

You can simply reply the class is-valid and is-invalid in a class ng-valid and ng-invalid, read the docs
.form-control.ng-invalid.ng-touched{
    border-color: #dc3545;
    padding-right: calc(1.5em + .75rem);
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 12 12' width='12' height='12' fill='none' stroke='%23dc3545'%3e%3ccircle cx='6' cy='6' r='4.5'/%3e%3cpath stroke-linejoin='round' d='M5.8 3.6h.4L6 6.5z'/%3e%3ccircle cx='6' cy='8.2' r='.6' fill='%23dc3545' stroke='none'/%3e%3c/svg%3e);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right calc(.375em + .1875rem) center;
    background-size: calc(.75em + .375rem) calc(.75em + .375rem);
}

.form-control.ng-valid.ng-touched{
    border-color: #198754;
    padding-right: calc(1.5em + .75rem);
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3e%3cpath fill='%23198754' d='M2.3 6.73L.6 4.53c-.4-1.04.46-1.4 1.1-.8l1.1 1.4 3.4-3.8c.6-.63 1.6-.27 1.2.7l-4 4.6c-.43.5-.8.4-1.1.1z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right calc(.375em + .1875rem) center;
    background-size: calc(.75em + .375rem) calc(.75em + .375rem);
}

You can also "binding" to the class is-valid and is-invalid in the way
  <input name="name" 
      #el="ngModel" 
     [class.is-valid]="el.valid && el.touched" 
     [class.is-invalid]="el.invalid && el.touched"
     [(ngModel)]="name" class="form-control" required />
  <div class="invalid-feedback">
    Please provide a valid city.
  </div>

Or even make a directive as
@Directive({
  selector: '.form-control',
  standalone:true
})
export class BootstrapError {
  @HostBinding('class.is-valid') get valid() { return this.control?.valid && this.control.touched; }
  @HostBinding('class.is-invalid') get invalid() { return this.control?.invalid && this.control.touched; }

  constructor(private control:NgControl){}
}

See that the selector is any control with the class form-control, So you only need import the directive. See that the directive also works using ReactiveForms
a stackblitz with the last two options (in the stacblitz, the directive has as selector .form-control.special to only apply to the last two inputs

Ended up getting this taken care of.  Our goal was to avoid changing the CSS directly (as Eliseo recommended).  And, even if you just replace "is-" with "ng-", the ":valid/:invalid" styles still applied and took precedence.
In the end, we were able to override the mixin that generated these styles.  It should then work if Bootstrap updates in the future, as well as applies to future releases for other projects.  We added this:
@mixin form-validation-state-selector($state) {
  @if ($state == "valid" or $state == "invalid") {
    .was-validated #{if(&, "&", "")}.ng-#{$state},
    #{if(&, "&", "")}.is-#{$state} {
      @content;
    }
  } @else {
    #{if(&, "&", "")}.is-#{$state} {
      @content;
    }
  }
}

within our own version of bootstrap.scss and placed it after /scss/mixin and before /scss/forms.  Doing that allowed this version to replace the default.  In my version, note I replaced ":" with ".ng-" on the third line.  This took out the HTML5 selectors and allowed it all to work off of the angular classes instead.  Got us where we needed to go without touching too much of the Bootstrap default package.

I came across the same problem when using reactive forms to validate form input and not wanting to mess with Bootstraps CSS. I used the following directive:
import { Directive, HostBinding, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
    selector: '[appIsInvalid]',
    standalone: true,
})
export class IsInvalidDirective {
    @Input() control!: FormControl; // the form control
    @Input() submitted!: boolean; // the submitted status of the parent form

    // sets bootstrap class 'is-invalid' on the form control host element
    @HostBinding('class.is-invalid')
    get invalid() {
        return this.control.errors && (this.control.touched || this.submitted);
    }
}



you can inject the NgControl in the constructor of your directive (this makes that the directive works also when we use template driven form and you needn't pass the formControl as input), see my updated anwers

i tried something like this, but kept getting controls that were ".form-control.is-invalid:valid" and the stylesheets couldn't make up their mind as to what to show.  for the most part, the ":valid" took over and i was still getting green/ok indicators.

@MattJames i set up my form as follows <form [formGroup]="personForm" #form="ngForm" novalidate></form> which i think disables any and all validation other than that provided by ReactiveFormsModule - this leaves clear separation of concerns, Angular validates the control, Bootstrap does the styling. As you can see from the directive I only needed to display an invalid control (it never sets valid, only adds or removes is-invalid)

@SamScholefield i have novalidate on my form and still get :valid/:invalid on my controls.  without any directive like this, everything still gets styled red/green - it's just wrong in these cases.

I would suggest removing the ngModel binding and using formControlName on the select instead; defining the initial value of the select as empty string when building out your form using NonNullableFormBuilder in the component.
